# axios get request return request failed with error 400

Tags: javascript, react-native, axios

I need help on solving this issue. I am new with react native and javascript. Now I am trying to hook up the react native application with API. This process require me to get the token first by `axios.post` before I can do `axios.get` to fetch the data.

Long story short, below is my code snippet for both.

```
... // code 
const TOKEN_URL = 'https://test.co/testing/tokens'
const DATA_URL = 'https://test.co/testing/data/page1'

const getToken = () => {
    axios.post(TOKEN_URL, {
        email: 'email',
        password: 'password',
        role: 'user'
    })
    .then((response) => {
    //console.log(response.data.token);
    return response.data.token;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    });
};

//'export' here is for use in other code: example onPress function
export const fetchDriver = () => {
    const config = {
        headers: {
            'Bearer': getToken()
        }
    };

    axios.get(DRIVER_URL, config)
        .then((response) => {
            console.log(response);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });            
};
```

My expected console log would be something like this

```
{
    "timestamp": 1510038433,
    "verb": "GET",
    "object": "student",
    "data": {
        "age": "12",
        "id": "90000",
        "name": "Test Student",
        "emergencyName": "asd",
        "createdAt": "2017-10-04T05:39:39+00:00"
    }
}
```

But I keep getting error saying `Request failed with status code 400`

I am using Expo to develop this app.

Detail on the error is like this

```
- node_modules/axios/lib/core/createError.js:16:24 in createError
- node_modules/axios/lib/core/settle.js:19:6 in settle
- node_modules/axios/lib/adapters/xhr.js:78:13 in handleLoad
- node_modules/event-target-shim/lib/event-target.js:172:43 in dispatchEvent
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Network/XMLHttpRequest.js:540:23 in 
setReadyState
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/Network/XMLHttpRequest.js:381:25 in 
__didCompleteResponse
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/vendor/emitter/EventEmitter.js:182:12 in 
emit
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:306:47 in 
__callFunction
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:108:26 in 
<unknown>
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:269:6 in 
__guard
- node_modules/react-native/Libraries/BatchedBridge/MessageQueue.js:107:17 in 
callFunctionReturnFlushedQueue
```

I do not have any authorization to edit the api/server if the error comes from there.

Please help me if there is any point that I have been missing out in the snippet.
Thank you for your help and suggestion.

Comment: Does your getToken() post return a valid token?

Comment: I checked by `console.log(response.data.token)` and it return the token correctly. I even try by hardcoded the token directly but the result still the same.

Comment: Did you change your code to the one that were on answer?
Because it looks same tho?

Answer (score 1):

sidenote, you forgot to return inside getToken

I'll just give you back story on why this happens.
Promises are asynchronous, so is your axios call. Therefore you need to somehow wait for first call result. Otherwise if you put `const a = axiosCall()` and try to use it right away the `a` value would be `Pending` (not a string tho).

For that you can use promises or async/await. I'll show you proper approach with promises. I've just copied your code and refactored it a bit. Also remember that `driver` is still a promise so you need to handle it as other things.

```js
const getToken = () => {
    axios.post(TOKEN_URL, {
        email: 'email',
        password: 'password',
        role: 'user'
    })
    .then((response) => {
    //console.log(response.data.token);
    return response.data.token;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    });
};

//'export' here is for use in other code: example onPress function
export const fetchDriver = () => {
    const config = {
        headers: {
            'Bearer': getToken()
        }
    };

    axios.get(DRIVER_URL, config)
        .then((response) => {
            console.log(response);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });            
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not chaining your requests. You have to wait till you get the token to be able to use it.

Something like this

getToken

```
const getToken = () => {
    return axios.post(TOKEN_URL, {
        email: 'email',
        password: 'password',
        role: 'user'
    })
    .then((response) => {
    //console.log(response.data.token);
    return response.data.token;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    });
};
```

fetchDriver

```
export const fetchDriver = () => {
  return getToken().then(token => {
    const config = {
      headers: {
        'Bearer': token
      }
    };

    return axios.get(DRIVER_URL, config)
      .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
      });
  });
}
```

Comment: it says `Unhandled promise rejection, [TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'getToken().then')]`

Comment: Are you importing `getToken`? Are both functions in the same file?

Comment: looks like you forgot to return the promise, ```return axios.post(TOKEN_URL, {...``` instead of ```axios.post(TOKEN_URL, {...```. I'll edit my answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to wait until token api get return response and after that You need make second api call with token

change like this

getToken : change to async function

```
const async getToken = () => {
    axios.post(TOKEN_URL, {
        email: 'email',
        password: 'password',
        role: 'user'
    })
    .then((response) => {
    //console.log(response.data.token);
    return response.data.token;
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
    });
};
```

fetchDriver : add await while calling getToken function

```
export const fetchDriver = () => {
    const config = {
        headers: {
            'Bearer': await getToken()
        }
    };

    axios.get(DRIVER_URL, config)
        .then((response) => {
            console.log(response);
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
        });            
};
```